# Is it possible to have fb:recommendations translated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-recommendations

When using the fb:recommendations box is it possible to pass a language parameter to have the box rendered in a language other than English?

Even if I have changed the language in my Facebook account to Spanish the box is still rendered in English on sites using this box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it is to load the javascript SDK using the appropriate locale as stated here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

```
//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js
```